# How to call php function from JavaScript using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, I want to create a dropdown menu with all the tags, but since it has more then 7.000, it needs to load only after the user click. I now it is only possible using Ajax, and I have started, but not accomplished yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/7kf1r9vw/2/

- In this Fiddle, after the click, this javascript file is loaded:
  `/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!`.
- The second example in Fiddle is just to show my actual code. I want that the results populated by the php funcion only starts after the user click.

But I don't know how to change it to a PHP function. Also, is it possible to add plain PHP script in the output or only with it embedded in a file?

Comment: You need to change your PHP code to do what you want when you send that request.

Comment: The PHP function is described here: [link](http://wphacks.com/how-to-display-wordpress-tags-dropdown-menu/). But I don't know how to add in the  getRequest(), because there there is a js, and I tried changing to a php file without success. Also, I didn't want to add another external file, I wanted to add it inline. Is is possible?

Comment: Javascript is client side, PHP is server side. You can't "call a function in PHP from Javscript." You need to make an AJAX request to a PHP url which contains your function.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Why don't you want to make another file? I recently had to redo a project that someone put _all their PHP_ into 2 files, which was a monster to sort through and convert to be more easily accessible and easier to develop which turned out to be around 30 new files and 111 new commits.

Comment: I do wonder about the basics of your approach. A drop-down list with 7,000 values is going to be a significant burden to both your user and to the browser itself. Have you considered an approach which presents users with a smaller and more easily manageable set?

Comment: @BobDill, it is a list of artists, and I'll add chosen to make the dropdown searchable. That way I think it would work. I came back to work in this again, and as I said, I tried just replacing the js file in the example, but it didn't work. How should be the php file? I'm working here: http://jsfiddle.net/7kf1r9vw/4/

Answer (score -1):

Your question appears to be "how do I call a php function on the server from my browser javascript code". In your code, you have the following function where the first parameter is the server side request:

```
function getSuccessOutput() {
  getRequest(
      '/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!', // demo-only URL
       drawOutput,

  );
  return false;
}
```

To change that to call a server php routine, you would change `'/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!'` to the url on your server you want to have executed: e.g. `'/myPHPFolder/someRoutine.php'` . The results will be delivered back to your req object.

In your initial html file (e.g. index.html, or where ever you start your flow), include the onload option on the body tag:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="yada yada yada">
    <meta name="author" content="you">
    <title>title for browser tab</title>
  </head>
  <body class="tutorial" onLoad="initPage()">
    <select id="optionList"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

This tells the browser to run the "initPage()" function with no parameters. The `initPage()` function then issues an async call and loads up your data, perhaps saving it to a local variable in the process.

```
function initPage()
{
    $('#optionList').empty(); // this ensures that you don't duplicate the info in the select list.
    $.when($.get('/myPHPFolder/someRoutine.php').done(function(res) 
    {   // if of interest, save the results to a cookie or variable.
        // you could also include a check to see if the data has already been downloaded.
        // This is a 'happy path' example, which does not include error checking from the host
        // build the optionList select HTML element
        for (let each in res)
        {(function(_idx, _arr)
            {
             // append the correct value to the select list. 
             // this example is based on returning a JSON object with an 
             // element called "id" which has the value I want to display in the options list
            $('#optionList').append('<option value="'+_arr[_idx].id+'">' +_arr[_idx].id+'</option>');})(each, res);
        }
        // create a function to execute when the user selects a different buyer
        $('#buyer').on('change', function() { /* do something useful here */ });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe better: how do I load a file that contains all the options? I think that executing this script every time a user clicks will still  be server expensive. So how would I just load a list of options in this code? <select name="tag-dropdown" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> <option value="#">Select an artist</option> <option id="output">Loading..</option> </select>

Comment: I will frequently use the HTML onload extension for the BODY tag to invoke a page initialization function. I would do this in your case to support a singleton query to the server. I'll edit my response to give you a code example.

Answer (score -1):

As Draco18s said, in your case, Javascript is executed client-side and PHP is executed server side.

In this case what you can do is a request to the server using Ajax.

For example, if you have the following html:

```
<select name="tag-dropdown" id="selectTags">
    <option value="#">Select an artist</option>
</select>
```

You can use Ajax to make a POST request to a PHP script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({ url: 'merge2.php',
      data: {operationName: "tagsNames"},
      type: 'post',
      success: function(output) {
            tagNamesres = JSON.parse(output);
            jQuery.each(tagNamesres, function(name, val) {
                                $("#selectTags").append('<option value="'+val+'">'+name+'</option>');
            });             
            }
  });
});
```

The PHP script can contain something like:

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST['operationName']) && !empty($_POST['operationName']) && $_POST["operationName"]=="tagsNames") {
    $resultarray = array();
    $resultarray["tagName1"] = "tagValue";
    $resultarray["tagName2"] = "tagValue2";
    echo json_encode($resultarray);
    return;
}
?>
```

In order to return something from the PHP function you need to print or use echo.
This is just an example so you could start working with this :)

For more information about how Ajax request works, read this http://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/

Comment: Or maybe better. How do I load a file that contains all the options? I think that executing this script every time a user clicks will be server expensive. So how would I just load a list of options in this code? `<select name="tag-dropdown" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();">
     <option value="#">Select an artist</option>
   <option id="output">Loading..</option>
    </select>`